# LU Factorization with Partial Pivoting Matlab

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

I'm trying to implement LU factorization with partial pivoting on PA (P being a permutation matrix, nxn) without explicitly interchanging rows or forming P. I've never created a LU factorization code without explicitly interchanging rows and it's proving to be difficult for me. Would anyone be able to help me?

```
function [L,U,P] = LUFact(A)
    %%LU Decomposition
    Ab = [A,b];
    n = length(A);
    L = eye(n);
    P = eye(n);

    %A(1,1) pivot
    %Row exchange 
    col1=Ab(:,1);
    [temp,idx] = max(col1);
    temp = Ab(1,:);
    Ab(1,:) = Ab(idx,:);
    Ab(idx,:) = temp;
    %Computation in the pivot column
    for i=2:n
        alpha = Ab(i,1) / Ab(1,1);
        L(i,1) = alpha;
        Ab(i,:) = Ab(i,:) - alpha*Ab(1,:);
    end
    %A(2,2) pivot
    %Row exchange
    col2 = Ab(2:end,2);
    [temp,idx] = max(col2);
    temp = Ab(2,:);
    Ab(2,:) = Ab(idx,:);
    Ab(idx,:) = temp;
    for i=3
        alpha = Ab(i,2) / Ab(2,2);
        L(i,2) = alpha;
        Ab(i,:) = Ab(i,:) - alpha*Ab(2,:);
    end
    U=Ab(1:n,1:n);
```

EDIT:

```
A = [2 1 1 0; 4 3 3 1; 8 7 9 5; 6 7 9 8];
b = [-1; 3; 2; 1];
n = size(A, 1);
L = eye(n);
U = eye(n);
Ab = [A b];

%Permutation Vector
p = zeros(n, 1);
for i = 1: 1: n
    p(i) = i;
end

%Finding L
for k = 1 : i-1
    L(i,k) = A(i,k);
    for j = 1 : k-1
        L(i,k) = L(i,k) - L(i,j)*U(j,k);
    end
    L(i,k) = L(i,k) / U(k,k);
end

%Finding U
for k = i : n
    U(i,k) = A(i,k);
    for j = 1 : i-1
        U(i,k) = U(i,k) - L(i,j)*U(j,k);
    end
end

for i = 1 : n
    L(i,i) = 1;
end

%Singularity
for z = 1 : n
if A(z,z) <= 0.000000001
    disp('Matrix A is singular.');
    disp('L =');
    disp(L);
    disp('U = ');
    disp(U);
else
%%Gaussian Elimination
x = zeros(n,1);
for k = 1 : 1 : n
    max = abs(A( p(k), p(k) ) );
    max_pos = k;
    if abs(A( p(1), p(k) ) ) > max
        max = abs(A(p(1), p(k)));
        max_pos = 1;
    end 
end

%Replace p_k element with max p element
temp_p = p;
p(k) = temp_p(max_pos);
p(max_pos) = temp_p(k);

%Elimination
for i = 1 : 1 : n
    if i~= k
        alpha = A(p(i), k) / A(p(k), k);
        for j = k : 1 : n
            A(p(i), j) = A(p(i), j) - alpha*A(p(k), j);
        end
    end
end

%Back-Substitution
for i = n: -1: 1
    x(i) = ( Ab(i, end) - Ab(i, i+1 : n)*x(i+1 : n) / Ab(i, i));
end

    disp('x = ');
    disp(x);
    disp('L = ');
    disp(L);
    disp('U = ');
    disp(U);
    disp(A);

end
end
```

Comment: Is there a reason to avoid using [`lu()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lu.html)?

Comment: @SecretAgentMan
I would really like to do it mostly from scratch, that's all.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: How to create a [mcve]?"

Comment: Is [this](https://chepusht.mathcs.wilkes.edu/LUwithPivoting.pdf) the math you're trying to implement?  I'd recommend [edit]ing your question to include (1) the math (linear algebra/matrix steps) you're trying to do, a [mcve] for an example problem, the correct answer for that example, and what you're code produces.  I think you'll get the most help from this site if you do that.

Comment: I realize my mistakes here. What I'm trying to do is perform LU factorization on a matrix by multiplying an nxn matrix A by an nx1 permutation vector. I reworked my code and now I can't seem to output the correct answer. I'm not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: I also added matrix A and vector b to test my code.